# ArrayList throwing syntax error "Unknown class"

Tags: java, android-studio

Doing some tutorials on java this simple foreach loop on a list is giving me an error in the foreach loop: "Unknown class: familyMembers". I dont see where the problem is. but i know is something simple. Thanks in advance.

Update: I have all the imports necessary.

```
    List<String> familyMembers = new ArrayList<String>();

    familyMembers.add("john");
    familyMembers.add("suzy");
    familyMembers.add("smith");

    for (String name : familyMembers){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, without any syntax or runtime errors.

Comment: Wich java version are you using and compiling? I am assuming you have imported java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: where is the for loop implemented? it looks like familyMembers is a local method declareated variable

Comment: Add your full class code and exception here

Comment: Sorry guys I just noticed That i had the code placed outside the function just  in the class. lol  I worked overnight and am learning java instead of going to sleep. Thanks for your quick replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like familyMembers is a method-locally declared variable

the for loop must be implemented in a method where the **familyMembers** can be access or scope